# Increase decimal place in SPSS output, frequency table

Tags: output, spss, decimalformat, cumulative-frequency

`I want to calculate Cumulative Percent for a continuous variable variable  (s_t_0001_dhi_Pd )

for that i used OMS function:

```
` `\`OMS
/SELECT CHARTS
/IF COMMANDS=\['Frequencies'\]
/DESTINATION VIEWER=YES
/TAG='ter'.

* OMS.
  OMS
 /SELECT TABLES
 /IF COMMANDS=\['Frequencies'\] SUBTYPES=\['Statistics'\] <br/>
 /DESTINATION VIEWER=YES.
 FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=s_t_0001_dhi_Pd
 /ORDER=ANALYSIS
  OMSEND.\`
``
```

my target variable is VAR4. the problem is that the output is limited to 2 decimal place , at my target variable, so i cant merge the file, here is he first rows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRZtp.png)
thanks!!`